# Can't remove text from label. Python, Tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-text, tkinter-label

Cannot understand what i did wrong here. A function named clearlabel should clear text from label1, but it says its not defined. Can you show me what I did wrong here?

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
w = (root.winfo_screenwidth() // 2) - 200
h = (root.winfo_screenheight() // 2) - 200
root.geometry('400x400+{}+{}'.format(w, h))
root.title("Pascal Triangle")



def PrintPasTriangle():
    row = [1]
    for i in range(int(ent.get())):
        label1 = Label(root, text=row, font = "Times 10")
        row = [sum(x) for x in zip([0]+row, row+[0])]
        label1.pack()
ent = Entry(root, width=50)
ent.pack()
ent.insert(0, "")


def clearlabel():
    label.delete("0", END)


myButton = Button(root, text="Show Triangle", font = "Times 10", command=PrintPasTriangle)
myButton.pack()

myButton2 = Button(root, text="Clear Triangle", font = "Times 10", command=clearlabel)
myButton2.pack()
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not an expert, but I believe the `label1` is lost as its not a global

You could ask your `root` for all the `widgets` it contains, and then `destroy` the `labels`.

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
w = (root.winfo_screenwidth() // 2) - 200
h = (root.winfo_screenheight() // 2) - 200
root.geometry('400x400+{}+{}'.format(w, h))
root.title("Pascal Triangle")



def PrintPasTriangle():
    row = [1]
    for i in range(int(ent.get())):
        label1 = Label(root, text=row, font = "Times 10")
        row = [sum(x) for x in zip([0]+row, row+[0])]
        label1.pack()
ent = Entry(root, width=50)
ent.pack()
ent.insert(0, "")


def clearlabel():
    #label1.delete("0", END)
    for widget in root.winfo_children():
        if isinstance(widget, Label):
            widget.destroy()
myButton = Button(root, text="Show Triangle", font = "Times 10", command=PrintPasTriangle)
myButton.pack()

myButton2 = Button(root, text="Clear Triangle", font = "Times 10", command=clearlabel)
myButton2.pack()
```

Comment: `root.winfo_children()` looks better than `root.pack_slaves()`. Even better if you store the widgets in a list.

Comment: yes! thanks, I couldn't remember what I had used previously and thats it.  Will update. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There are few issues in your code:

- `label1` is a local variable inside `PrintPasTriangle()`, so it cannot be accessed outside the function
- you have used same variable `label1` for all the *rows*, so only the last one is referenced
- you have used `label` instead of `label1` inside `clearlabel()`
- you have used undefined function `.delete(0, END)` on a label widget

I would suggest to create `label1` once outside the function for the Pascal Triangle instead of using multiple labels and update its text inside the two functions using `.config()`

```py
...

def PrintPasTriangle():
    row = [1]
    triangle = '1'
    for i in range(1, int(ent.get())):
        row = [sum(x) for x in zip([0]+row, row+[0])]
        triangle += "\n" + " ".join(str(x) for x in row)
    label1.config(text=triangle)

...

def clearlabel():
    label1.config(text='')

...

label1 = Label(root, font="Times 12")
label1.pack()

root.mainloop()
```